# how to show labels in right side in chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, highcharts

I make a simple chart .I am using hightchart js files . I am able to make chart but I have one issue I need the label should display on right side as shown in image .I am also able to make this song fussion chart please check my fiddle of fussion chart .
http://jsfiddle.net/Tu57h/139/

but I need to use hight chart .can we add label in right as shown in image and above fiddle using hight chart

here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/ogwsL7j3/1/

```
[![$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average fruit consumption during one week'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 250,
            y: 300,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: \[
                'Monday',
                'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday',
                'Thursday',
                'Friday',
                'Saturday',
                'Sunday'
            \]
        },]
```

Answer (score 0):

Aligning right may not be supported as per the Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/labels-align-left/): change `left` to `right`.
But you can atleast align left:

Change labels from 
`labels: { enabled:false }`
to

```
yAxis: {
    labels:{
          align: 'left'
      },
    title: {
        text: ''        
    }
}
```

Comment: can we add trend lines ..?

Comment: Yes, as per the example it gets added automatically (horizontal lines)

Comment: is theer another library which support trend lien make same charts as above

Comment: Actually I want to make same charts as shown in images ..so I need to add three trend lines as shown in image with red color

Comment: I just googled [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/). But I havent used too many...

Comment: my motive is to make  same chart as shown in above image

Comment: I saw all this link but no one provide same trend lines as shown in image ..:( ok I will try

Comment: Actually I make this http://jsfiddle.net/Tu57h/139/ which is similar to above image but it tooptip is not similar to above image

Comment: Check out this [page](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/highcharts_trendline) and its demos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88975/discussion-between-user944513-and-threesidedcoin).

Comment: could you add this in my demo fiddle

Comment: Use a plotLine to add a horizotal line. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines. Inside you can define a label and position by x param.